GAM Leave one out cross validation (LOOCV) for biggish models
I have fitted a relatively complex/large generalized additive model for prediction purposes but would like to assess its predictive power/cross-validate it. Due to variability in observed data and the computational power necessary to do an iterative testing and training dataset, I thought I would be able to leverage some of the model's internal workings (e.g., Hhat, lpmatrix, etc.) to perform a leave-one-out cross-validation (LOOCV).
Below is some general code (and toy data) as a reproducible working example. This model produces similar results on what I think is the correct cross-validation side of things. The real models are much larger and more complex (a couple more smoothing terms and more data). First, is this the correct/proper way to do LOOCV? Secondly, I noticed that the predicted values in rslt$predictions and associated fit metrics are rather high, did I miss something?
I feel like I missing one or two steps here but not sure where I messed up.

Working Example
library(mgcv)
library(tweedie)
library(DHARMa)
set.seed(123)

# Generate example data
n <- 100
x1 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x2 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
eta <- 2 + 3 * sin(2*pi*x1) + 2 * x2^2
mu <- exp(eta)  # Using log link
p <- 1.5  # Tweedie power parameter
phi <- 0.5  # Dispersion parameter

# Generate Tweedie responses using tweedie package
y <- rtweedie(n, mu=mu, phi=phi, power=p)

# Create dataset
data <- data.frame(y=y, x1=x1, x2=x2)

# Fit Tweedie GAM
tweedie_model <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2), 
                     family = tw(),
                     data = data,
                     method="GCV.Cp")
summary(tweedie_model)

layout(matrix(1:4,2,2))
gam.check(tweedie_model,pch=21,bg="grey")
abline(0,1,col="red")

DHARMa::testResiduals(simulateResiduals(tweedie_model))

# LOOCV function specifically for Tweedie
# Get influence measures
H <- influence(tweedie_model)

# Get fitted values and actual values
y <- model.frame(tweedie_model)[,1]
mu <- fitted(tweedie_model)
eta <- tweedie_model$linear.predictor

# Get Tweedie parameters
p <- tweedie_model$family$getTheta(TRUE)

# Calculate variance and weights
variance <- mu^p
w <- 1/variance

# Calculate working residuals for Tweedie
z <- eta + (y - mu)/(mu^(p-1))

# Calculate LOOCV predictions
eta_cv <- (z - eta) / (1 - H) + eta
predictions <- tweedie_model$family$linkinv(eta_cv)

# Calculate error metrics
mse <- mean((y - predictions)^2)
rmse <- sqrt(mse)
mae <- mean(abs(y - predictions))

rslt <- list(
  predictions = predictions,
  actual = y,
  mse = mse,
  rmse = rmse,
  mae = mae,
  hat_diag = H
)

round(rslt$rmse, 3)
round(rslt$mae, 3)

# 1. Actual vs Predicted
plot(rslt$actual, rslt$predictions,
     xlab="Actual Values", ylab="LOOCV Predicted Values",
     main="Actual vs Predicted")
abline(0,1, col="red")

# 2. Residuals vs Predicted
residuals <- rslt$actual - rslt$predictions
plot(rslt$predictions, residuals,
     xlab="Predicted Values", ylab="Residuals",
     main="Residuals vs Predicted")
abline(h=0, col="red")

# 3. Histogram of residuals
hist(residuals, main="Histogram of Residuals",
     xlab="Residuals", breaks=20)

# 4. Leverage (hat values) distribution
hist(rslt$hat_diag, main="Distribution of Hat Values",
     xlab="Hat Values", breaks=20)

After some reading, I came across the idea of using the lpmatrix, which produces much more reason (looking), but I am still wondering if it is the correct approach (did I do the math right, is this consistent with the methodology, etc.).
# Compute the linear predictor matrix and fitted values
Xp <- predict(tweedie_model, type = "lpmatrix")
fitted_values <- predict(tweedie_model, type = "response")

# Extract weights and compute leverage (diagonal of hat matrix)
W <- diag(tweedie_model$weights)  # Observation weights
H <- Xp %*% solve(t(Xp) %*% W %*% Xp) %*% t(Xp) %*% W  # Hat matrix
h <- diag(H)  # Leverage values

# Compute residuals
residuals <- y - fitted_values

# Approximate LOOCV predictions
loocv_preds <- fitted_values - (residuals * h) / (1 - h)

# Calculate prediction errors or RMSE
loocv_errors <- y - loocv_preds
sqrt(mean(loocv_errors^2)); #rmse
mean(abs(loocv_errors)); #mae

# 1. Actual vs Predicted
plot(y, loocv_preds,
     xlab="Actual Values", ylab="LOOCV Predicted Values",
     main="Actual vs Predicted")
abline(0,1, col="red")

# 2. Residuals vs Predicted
plot(loocv_preds, loocv_errors,
     xlab="Predicted Values", ylab="Residuals",
     main="Residuals vs Predicted")
abline(h=0, col="red")

# 3. Histogram of residuals
hist(loocv_errors, main="Histogram of Residuals",
     xlab="Residuals", breaks=20)

# 4. Leverage (hat values) distribution
hist(h, main="Distribution of Hat Values",
     xlab="Hat Values", breaks=20)

Unfortunately, when I apply this approach to the actual model, when calculating the H variable using this approach I get this error. I haven't been able to figure out if it's because of the complexity of the model, variability in the data, or something else.
Error in solve.default(t(Xp) %*% W %*% Xp) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.39525e-33

Any insight or tips would be appreciated.
EDIT
After some reading, tinkering with the code and comparing outputs I confirmed the suspicion that
W <- diag(tweedie_model$weights)  # Observation weights
H <- Xp %*% solve(t(Xp) %*% W %*% Xp) %*% t(Xp) %*% W  # Hat matrix
h <- diag(H)  # Leverage values

is the long way (and approximates) this
h <- influence(tweedie_model)

But it seems that influence is much more stable? Therefore I tried a hybrid the of the two approaches above.
 h <- influence(tweedie_model)
# Compute residuals
residuals <- y - fitted_values

# Approximate LOOCV predictions
loocv_preds <- fitted_values - (residuals * h) / (1 - h)

# Calculate prediction errors or RMSE
loocv_errors <- y - loocv_preds
sqrt(mean(loocv_errors^2)); #rmse
mean(abs(loocv_errors)); #mae

But the original question still stands, is this the proper way to validate a model and assess predictiveness (if that is a word)? Also, Does influence take into account the distribution family used in the model?

First, regarding your approach to LOOCV: While using the hat matrix (H) for LOOCV is computationally efficient and theoretically sound for many models, there are some potential issues with your current implementation:
The working residuals calculation for Tweedie models is more complex than the current formula suggests. The relationship between the response and linear predictor in Tweedie models is non-linear, and the variance function depends on both μ and p.
The current implementation assumes the working residuals behave similarly to those in a standard GLM, but Tweedie models have additional complexity due to their compound Poisson-gamma nature.
Regarding the high predicted values: This is likely occurring because:
The leverage correction (1 - H) in the denominator can become unstable when H values are close to 1
The working residuals calculation might not properly account for the Tweedie-specific variance structure
Here's a suggested modification that might be more appropriate:
# Modified LOOCV for Tweedie GAM
loocv_tweedie <- function(model) {
  n <- nrow(model$model)
  predictions <- numeric(n)
  
  # Get model matrix and response
  X <- predict(model, type="lpmatrix")
  y <- model.frame(model)[,1]
  
  # Get coefficients and Tweedie parameters
  beta <- coef(model)
  p <- model$family$getTheta(TRUE)
  phi <- summary(model)$scale
  
  # Perform LOOCV
  for(i in 1:n) {
    # Create weights for leave-one-out
    w <- rep(1, n)
    w[i] <- 0
    
    # Fit model without observation i
    fit_i <- gam(y ~ X - 1, 
                 weights=w,
                 family=tw(link="log", p=p),
                 offset=rep(0, n))
    
    # Predict for held-out observation
    pred_i <- predict(fit_i, newdata=data.frame(X=X[i,]), type="response")
    predictions[i] <- pred_i
  }
  
  # Calculate metrics
  mse <- mean((y - predictions)^2)
  rmse <- sqrt(mse)
  mae <- mean(abs(y - predictions))
  
  return(list(
    predictions = predictions,
    actual = y,
    mse = mse,
    rmse = rmse,
    mae = mae
  ))
}

This modified approach:
Explicitly fits n models, each leaving out one observation
Properly handles the Tweedie-specific parameters
Avoids potential issues with the hat matrix approximation
Maintains the proper variance structure throughout the prediction process
While this is computationally more intensive than the hat matrix approach, it should provide more reliable results for Tweedie GAMs. For very large datasets, you might want to consider:
Using k-fold cross-validation instead of LOOCV
Implementing a more efficient version using update() rather than refitting the entire model
Using parallel processing for the loop

Is this answer written by generative AI/LLMs?

So hard to tell @Firebug, I’ve been trying to figure that out for many answers. What makes you say that, the “here’s a suggested modification” part?
